# Hello this is a simple program in C++. It calculates the temperature from Fahrenheit, Parenthesis Math Result Error

Tags: c++, math, parentheses, temperature

When I wrap `5/9` in parenthesis, the result is 0, but when I don't put in the parenthesis, the result is correct.  Why is this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double temperature_farenheit = 195;
    std::cout << "Enter the temperature in Farenheit: ";
    std::cin >> temperature_farenheit;
    double temperature_celsius;
    temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit - 32) * (5 / 9);
    std::cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << temperature_celsius;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the temperature in Farenheit: 47
The temperature in Celsius is: 0
```

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double temperature_farenheit = 195;
    std::cout << "Enter the temperature in Farenheit: ";
    std::cin >> temperature_farenheit;
    double temperature_celsius;
    temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
    std::cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << temperature_celsius;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the temperature in Farenheit: 47
The temperature in Celsius is: 8.33333
```

---

I did a quick example in Python just to test the result, and the output is correct, but I don't know why the result is incorrect in C++.

```py
temperature_farenheit = 47
temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit-32)*(5/9)
print(temperature_celsius)
```

Output:

```
8.333333333333334
```

---

C++ is incorrect, but why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double temperature_farenheit = 47;
    double temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit - 32) * (5 / 9);
    std::cout << "47F is equal in Celsius to : " << temperature_celsius;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
47F is equal in Celsius to : 0
```

I tried putting the fraction at the beginning or at the end. Mathematically both are correct, but for some reason C++ is reporting 0 as a result when I put in parenthesis.

Comment: Please, don't abuse tags - `python` tag removed

Comment: `5/9==0` because integer division. Put a dot after the `5.` or `9.`.

Comment: Sometimes you want to do integer division, one integer divided by another, with the result also an integer. In C++ you use `/` for this, no doubt in python you use something else. Don't expect C++ to be like python, C++ is it's own thing.

Comment: The reason for the difference without brackets is in that case left to right associativity means that the multiplication happens first so you are not dividing one integer by another, so in that case you do not get integer division.

Answer (score 2):

Integer division `5/9 == 0`. Just put a dot after the 5 or the 9 to make the fraction a floating point number.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double temperature_farenheit;
    std::cout << "Enter the temperature in Farenheit: ";
    std::cin >> temperature_farenheit;
    double temperature_celsius;
    temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit - 32) * (5. / 9);
    std::cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << temperature_celsius;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces

```
Enter the temperature in Farenheit: 70
The temperature in Celsius is: 22.2222
```

Also you do not need to initialize `temperature_fahrenheit` if you are going to read it from cin.

Godbolt:
https://godbolt.org/z/as8fjvsGT

Answer (score 2):

In C++, division of two integers results in an integer result.  If at least one of the parameters is double the result is double.  So:

```cpp
(47.0-32) * (5 / 9)
   15.0 *   (  0  )
         0
```

But:

```cpp
(47.0-32) * 5 / 9
   15.0   * 5 / 9      // evaluated left-to-right without parentheses
   75.0       / 9
      8.333333
```

In `(5/9)` if you make one of the constants double, e.g. `(5./9)` you'll get the double answer.

In Python 3.x, operator `/` is always a `float` result and `//` is an *integral* result.  The result type of `//` is `int` if both operands are type `int`; otherwise `float`, but still integral:

```py
>>> 75 / 9
8.333333333333334
>>> 75 // 9
8
>>> 75. // 9
8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic operations are evaluated from left to right, and for each two operands of an operation the compiler determines the common type of the operands of the operation. Due to the usual arithmetic conversions, an operand of an integer type is converted to the type `double` if the other operand has the type `double`.

From the C++17 Standard (8 Expressions):

> 11 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
> enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
> way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
> the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
> which are defined as follows:
>
> (11.1) — If either operand is of scoped enumeration type (10.2), no
> conversions are performed; if the other operand does not have the same
> type, the expression is ill-formed.
>
> (11.2) — If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be
> converted to long double.
>
> (11.3) — Otherwise, **if either operand is double, the other shall be
> converted to double.**
>
> ...

So, if you will write, for example:

```
temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
```

then the compiler parses this statement like:

```
temperature_celsius = ( (temperature_farenheit - 32) * 5 ) / 9;
```

As a result, the integer constant `5` is converted to the type `double` because the left operand `(temperature_farenheit - 32)`  has the type `double`, by the same reason because `temperature_farenheit` has the type `double`.

If you use parentheses then the expression in the parentheses `(5 / 9)` is evaluated first using integer arithmetic, and its result is equal to the integer `0` because the common type of the operands is `int`.

To force the compiler to evaluate the expression in the parentheses as an expression of the type `double`, you could write for example `(5.0 / 9)`. In this case, the first operand has the type `double`, and according to the provided quote from the C++17 Standard the second operand `9` will be converted to the type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

`5` and `9` are literals of type `int`.

When you use the parenthesis around `5 / 9`:

`temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit - 32) * (5 / 9);`

You are performing **integer division**.  `5` divided by `9` is `0.555...`, but the decimal gets truncated off, leaving the result as just `0`.  And any value multiplied by `0` results in `0`.

If you omit the parenthesis around `5 / 9`:

`temperature_celsius = (temperature_farenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;`

Now you are performing **floating-point division**, because the `*` and `/` operators have the same [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), but are evaluated from left to right, so the compiler behaves *as-if* you had written it like this:

`temperature_celsius = ((temperature_farenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;`

Thus, the multiplication is evaluated before the division. First the result of `(temperature_farenheit - 32)` (a `double`) is multiplied by `5`, yielding a `double` result, and then that result is divided by `9`, yielding a final `double` result that has its decimal intact.

The reason you don't have this issue in Python is because it doesn't have separate `/` operators for integer and floating-point arithmetic.  The output of the `/` operator is always a floating-point.  For integer division, you have to use the `//` operator instead.